# How to call AAD-protected azure function from PowerBI

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, powerbi, azure-functions, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to call an Azure function that is protected by AAD from Power BI.

In Power BI I go to "Home -> Get Data -> Web" then paste function app URL and try login with "Organizational account". This is what I get:

[image]

I have added the following permissions to my application in Azure Portal:

[image]

And this is the Authentication setup for the application

[image]

Any ideas how to get past the error?

Comment: I am getting this error too. Did you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the AAD authentication config in the function app and check if the function url is present in the allowed token audiences.

i would also try to assign admin consent to the application by using the url bellow: changing the fields

[https://login.microsoftonline.com/[tenant_name_in_onmicrosoft.com-form]/oauth2/authorize?client_id=[appId]&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http://your-uri-here&nonce=1234&resource=https://graph.windows.net&prompt=admin_consent](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%5Btenant_name_in_onmicrosoft.com-form%5D/oauth2/authorize?client_id=%5BappId%5D&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http://your-uri-here&nonce=1234&resource=https://graph.windows.net&prompt=admin_consent)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried this, but it didn't solve the issue. Any other suggestions?